# JS .includes() method to search on a string variable created from a text file using jQuery.get

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have on my html two inputs (text and button) for the user to type and submit:

```
<input type="text" id="userInput">
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="search()">
```

And I'm storing this input inside a variable:

```
var userInput
function search(){
    userInput = document.getElementById("userInput").value
    userInput = userInput.toString().toLowerCase()
}
```

I'm getting the full string that I want to search inside from a jQuery.get and storing it on a variable called **data**:

```
var data
$.get("foo.txt", function(response) {
    data = response
});
```

And then I'm using a if condition to do stuff based on If I could find the userInput inside the String from the .txt file (stored in the data variable) or not:

```
if (data.includes(userInput) == true) {
    console.log('found it!')
} else {
    console.log('nah')
}
```

But my **data variable is getting undefined**... I'm guessing it is because it gets a value inside the $.get. I'm new to JS, can't figure out how to make this work. Anyone can help me?

Note: I can log the data variable and see the text file content inside of it.

Full code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="userInput">
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="search()">
<script>

    var userInput
    function search(){
        userInput = document.getElementById("userInput").value
        userInput = userInput.toString().toLowerCase()
    }

    var data
    $.get("foo.txt", function(response) {
        data = response
    });

    if (data.includes(userInput) == true) {
        console.log('found it!')
    } else {
        console.log('nah')
    }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this because of: "*var is function-scoped, meaning that variables instantiated with the keyword would only be accessible to code within the function*", right?

Can anyone help me find a solution for that?

Comment: Move that `if()` inside the `$.get` callback function. Ajax is asynchronous. You are trying to eat a pizza before it gets delivered. The delivery is inside the callback

Comment: Oh, I see, I did fixed the nesting there and it worked, thank you, I'll read more about it <3